# Laravel set environment variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Trying to set the environment variable from commandline like

`php artisan serve --env=someenv`

But a `var_dump(App::environment())` outputs `string 'production' (length=10)`.

Shouldn't it be `someenv` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This environment you set on `php artisan seve` is just for that particular command, running on cli.

Note that this is not you application running, just a webserver, provided by PHP so you don't need to install a full apache or nginx to test your application.

Your web application will run under a different environment and you still need to provide a correct environment adding it to your bootstrap/start.php file:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'example.com'),

));
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5 can use a *.env* file in your installation base directory to determine your environment. For example, to set the current environment as the „local“ one, create a file *.env* with

```
APP_ENV = local
```

Please see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365621/laravel-5-doesnt-read-values-from-dot-env-files) for more details on this mechanism.