# Laravel 5 doesn't read values from dot ENV files

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-environment

I don't know if this question is relevant or not. LARAVEL 5 is still in developmental phase. I have pulled LARAVEL 5 after watching one of the Laracast video about new features in LARAVEL 5. I couldn't resist to wait for its formal release.

I named the local environment `dot` file as `.env.local.php`. But for some reason I am unable to get the the values from this dot file when using `$_ENV['KEY']`.

I am quite sure that I have configured the environment correctly. When doing `$app->environment()` shows the correct environment. Has it been changed in LARAVEL 5 the way we get the values from dot files or am I missing something ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to set ENV variables in Laravel 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346299/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-env-variables-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default in `environment.php` file you have something like that:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../.env'))
{
    Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');
}
```

so only `.env` file is being read (notice `.env` not `.env.php` - so you should rename your file - or you can add as 2nd parameter file name `.env.php` if you want). Any other environment files (`.local.env`) are not being read by default - you will need to load them manually.

If you don't have such code by default, you should probably update/install Laravel 5 again (changes appear very often)

Now, I don't know what method you use, but you can put in your `.env` file also your environment name in for example `APP_ENV` variable, create `.local.env` file with content you want and then you could use in `environment.php` file:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../.env'))
{
    Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');

    if (getenv('APP_ENV') && file_exists(__DIR__.'/../.' .getenv('APP_ENV') .'.env')) {
        echo "loading";
        Dotenv::load(__DIR__ . '/../', '.' . getenv('APP_ENV') . '.env');
    }

}
```

If you don't want to do it this way, you can probably change the other and load env file you want based on `$env` assuming you use PC based environment detection.

If it's unclear you can also look at [What's the correct way to set ENV variables in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346299/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-env-variables-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Very clear now. So it seems Mr. Otwell has favoured something else over PC based environment detection. Although I liked PC based, but again he must have good reason behind it

Comment: And where is that file - environment.php?

Comment: I did not find environment.php in 5.2