# Laravel 5 : How to set environment mode

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-environment

I mm trying to set 3 mode in laravel 5 **Example** :  **mode local , staging , production**

I am setting environment 3 mode in `.env` but I try to separate to 
.local.env , .staging.env and production.env  someone here have any idea to do like this ?

> Now i'm try in .env  -> APP_ENV to 3 mode right now :)

Thank you

Comment: I think it should be 3 separate .env files

`.env` is used on production, then `.env.staging` is on your staging. Finally `.env.local` on your development machine

Comment: @lozadaOmr thanks for sharing a good idea .i try to built same route to 3 mode :) now .

Comment: @lozadaOmr i found some good way too . This link **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365621/laravel-5-doesnt-read-values-from-dot-env-files**

Comment: Just a correction my previous comment was based on using Laravel 4.2, apparently things are different in Laravel 5 see dynamic's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers/comments are wrong.

You only store **one** .env per environment. That is:

- Your local machine will have a .env with your local config
- The staging maching will have a .env with your staging config, 
  and
- Your production maching will have a .env with your production config

So it is always one .env file per machine. Laravel will load that config from that file.

*note that .env file is in .gitignore, .env.example is **not***

---

When testing on local machine using PHPUnit you can add env variables in phpunit.xml

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="true"/>
    <env name="APP_KEY" value="some crazy value"/>
    <env name="DB_DRIVER" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
</php>
```

Comment: Exactly, I dont understand why people don't read documentation, its all there, and also it is mentioned in one (recent) episode of Laravel Podcasts.